# Struts2 Select UI tag: problem with rendering in Firefox with selected item

Tags: firefox, xhtml, struts2

I have problem with Struts2 select UI tag. Firefox doesn't show selected item. I have code in JSP:

```
<s:select list="allCategories"  value="2" listKey="id" listValue="categoryName" name="selectedCategory"  key="shortcut.add.category" required="true" />
```

It renders into:

```
<select gtbfieldid="49" name="selectedCategory" id="inputShortcuts_selectedCategory">
<option value="1">23456</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Catg1</option>
<option value="3">updated</option>

<option value="6">Category</option>
</select>
```

When I open this action in IE, it renders fine (option Catg1 is selected by default). But Firefox (3.6) shows first option as selected. How can I resolve it? I use xhtml theme of Struts2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generated HTML displays correctly for me in Firefox 3.6.11. Have you confirmed that you are not viewing a cached version of the page? I see that `gtbfieldid` is being added to the rendered output. Isn't that from Google Toolbar? Perhaps that is interfering with something?

I can't see anything visibly wrong with your select element that would prohibit it from working properly in any browser.

Comment: Thanks! Really, it was false alarm. I redeployed app and it works, thanks!